# Rest Countries API TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am completing a frontendmentor challenge, rest countries api. So far I have managed to build the  countries list and I'm currently building the country details page which just displays information about each country. I have encountered a TypeError (TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
) and I'm struggling to see the issue.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
  CountryDetailStyles,
  ImgContainer,
  CountryInfo,
  CountryInfoDetails,
  CountryDetailsWrapper,
  CountryInfoDetailsInner,
  CountryBorders,
  LinkWrapper,
  Button,
  ButtonWrapper,
} from '../styles/CountryDetailStyles';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

function CountryDetail({ match }) {
  const [country, setCountry] = useState([]);

  const matchingCountry = match.params.name;

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getCountry() {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `https://restcountries.com/v2/name/${matchingCountry}`
      );
      setCountry(response.data);
    }

    getCountry();
  }, []);

  // get borders full name using alpha3code
  const getBorderCountryName = (country, border) => {
    const matchingCountry = country.find((country) => {
      return country.alpha3Code === border;
    });

    return matchingCountry.name;
  };

  return (
    <CountryDetailStyles>
      <Link className="country-links" to={'/'}>
        <LinkWrapper>
          <p>
            <i className="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>Go Back
          </p>
        </LinkWrapper>
      </Link>
      {country.map(
        (i) =>
          i.name.toLowerCase() === matchingCountry && (
            <CountryDetailsWrapper>
              <ImgContainer src={i.flag} />
              <CountryInfo>
                <h1>{i.name}</h1>
                <CountryInfoDetails>
                  <CountryInfoDetailsInner>
                    <p>
                      <span>Native Name: </span>
                      {i.nativeName}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      <span>Population: </span>
                      {i.population.toLocaleString()}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      <span>Region: </span>
                      {i.region.length > 0 ? i.region : 'N/A'}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      <span>Sub Region: </span>
                      {i.subregion.length > 0 ? i.subregion : 'N/A'}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      <span>Capital: </span>
                      {i.capital.length > 0 ? i.capital : 'N/A'}
                    </p>
                  </CountryInfoDetailsInner>
                  <CountryInfoDetailsInner className="second">
                    <p>
                      <span>Top Level Domain: </span>
                      {i.topLevelDomain}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      <span>Currencies: </span>
                      {i.currencies[0].name}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      <span>Languages: </span>
                      {i.languages.map((lang) => lang.name).join(', ')}
                    </p>
                  </CountryInfoDetailsInner>
                </CountryInfoDetails>
                <CountryBorders>
                  <p>
                    <span>Border Countries: </span>
                    {!i.borders && 'N/A'}
                    {i.borders.map((border) => {
                      const borderName = getBorderCountryName(country, border);
                      return (
                        <ButtonWrapper>
                          <Link
                            className="country-links"
                            to={`/country/${borderName && borderName.toLowerCase()}`}
                          >
                            <Button>{borderName}</Button>
                          </Link>
                        </ButtonWrapper>
                      );
                    })}
                  </p>
                </CountryBorders>
              </CountryInfo>
            </CountryDetailsWrapper>
          )
      )}
    </CountryDetailStyles>
  );
}

export default CountryDetail;
```

Comment: Can you paste the full error you are getting?

Comment: i dont' understand, that's the full error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Comment: I am not sure that why are you only getting that, try to change `const matchingCountry = match.params.name || 'country';` And try to debug it. I am not sure whether it will solve your problem or not. Since that's the only thing I can think of where an error can pop up.